# Excel - Skip Blanks and re-display data in Office 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a spreadsheet that displays players names if they haven't been previously chosen on another sheet.

This means I have two columns that look like this

```
      Column J    Column K
101   Position    Player
102   Blank       Blank
103   Defender    Blank
104   Defender    Blank
105   Defender    Player 1
106   Midfielder  Player 2
107   Midfielder  Blank
108   Midfielder  Blank
109   Forward     Player 3
110   Forward     Blank
111   Forward     Blank
```

I then have a separate table to display these Players

```
      Column N   Column O
101   Blank      Players
102   Sub 1      Blank
103   Sub 2      Blank
104   Sub 3      Blank
```

Column K will change depending on which players are chosen elsewhere.

There will always be 3 players in Column K, but in different positions.

I want to repeat the name of that player in Column O, to assign them to Sub 1, Sub 2 and Sub 3.

I have tried various `IFERROR=...` to no avail. It either returns nothing, or a 0. I am not sure if this is a limitation of the Online version of Office 365 Excel.

Comment: Do you mean `=FILTER(K:K,(ROW(K:K)<>1)*(K:K<>""))` ?

Comment: That produces a 0

Comment: Is `Blank` in your example text or actual Blank? Otherwise `=FILTER(K:K,(ROW(K:K)<>1)*(K:K<>"Blank"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in cell O102:

```
=INDEX(K:K,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$102:$K$111)/($K$102:$K$111<>""),ROW(O102)-ROW($O$102)+1))
```

You can drag it down to the others cell.

Excel in office 365 will probably have a easier solution, but this one should work too.

Comment: I added this in to Cell O102 and dragged it down and it gives me a 0 in each box. (O102, O103 and O104)

This is the issue I was running into.

Comment: That's weird. Can you please click on the cell O102, select the part of the formula from `AGGREGATE(` to `+1)` both included and press F9? What does it returns? By the way: i forgot make the range K102:K111 absolute so i've corrected the formula.

Comment: F9 doesn't produce any results. I think this is just a limitation of Office 365 Web Version

Comment: How can the aggregate function produce no result and yet the index returns a zero? It has to return a number of any sort or the index would return an error. Do you confirm that the formula `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$102:$K$111)/($K$102:$K$111<>""),ROW(O102)-ROW($O$102)+1)` return a blank cell?

Comment: I have NO IDEA why, but this just started working.

So, your top answer is correct and I will mark it as such. Thank you!